# Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array while trying to consume a SOAP web service in .NET 6

Tags: .net-core, soap

I am trying to consume a SOAP service in a .NET 6 C# project. I had to implement a custom binding to handle the issue of mismatch of the char encoding. Code compiles but I get a run time exception

> Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array

Here is the snippet of my code:

```
var customTextEncoding = new CustomTextMessageBindingElement("iso-8859-1", "text/xml", MessageVersion.Soap11);
var httpTransport = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
var binding = new CustomBinding(customTextEncoding, httpTransport);
```

The exception is thrown on the 3rd line.

I have implemented the `CustomTextMessageBindingElement` in a class.

I am unable to figure out what I am doing wrong. Thanks for the help.

EDIT:

I rearranged my code to the following:

```
var customTextEncoding = (BindingElement)(new CustomTextMessageBindingElement("iso-8859-1", "text/xml", MessageVersion.Soap11));
var httpTransport = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
var collection = new BindingElementCollection();
collection.Add(customTextEncoding);
collection.Add(httpTransport);
var binding = new CustomBinding(collection);
```

Now I get exception at the line where I am adding httpTransport to the collection. It thinks httpTransport is not of type BindingElement.
The exception I get now is

> System.ArrayTypeMismatchException: Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array.

I am running this code in AWS Lambda under .Net 6 runtime.

EDIT:
I created a console app on my Mac and all works great, exact same code. It looks like this has to do with the AWS Lambda environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and after updating System.ServiceModel.* nuget packages to 6.0.0 version, problem solved.