# How can I fix this 'Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array.' error on my WCF Reference?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, soap, dotnet-svcutil

I was given a WSDL and generated a client Reference using Visual Studio's SVCUtil tool.
I am using .net Core 6.

#### This generated function is throwing an exception:

```cs
 private static Binding GetBindingForEndpoint()
 {
     CustomBinding result = new();
     result.Elements.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(){
         MessageVersion = MessageVersion.CreateVersion(System.ServiceModel.EnvelopeVersion.Soap12, AddressingVersion.None)
     });
     HttpsTransportBindingElement httpsBindingElement = new()
     {
         AllowCookies = true,
         MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue,
         MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue
     };
     result.Elements.Add(httpsBindingElement);

     return result;
 }
```

This seems like such a low level issue I'm not sure what the cause is, but the line 'result.Elements.Add(httpsBindingElement);' throws an error

#### Exception:

System.ArrayTypeMismatchException: 'Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array.'

```
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    System.Collections.Generic.List<T>.Insert(int, T) in List.cs
    System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>.Add(T) in Collection.cs
    MyService.MyServiceOrderServicesSoapClient.GetBindingForEndpoint() in Reference.cs
    MyService.MyServiceOrderServicesSoapClient.MyServiceOrderServicesSoapClient(MyService.MyServiceOrderServicesSoapClient.EndpointConfiguration) in Reference.cs
    MyProject.Services.API_Tools.MyServiceAPITools.GetVR() in MyServiceAPITools.cs
```

#### Things to note:

- result.Elements is a List<BindingElement>.
- HttpsTransportBindingElement and TextMessageEncodingBindingElement are subclasses of BindingElement

My understanding of the error is it is unable to insert the HttpsTransportBindingElement into the List<BindingElements> because the type is incorrect, even though it is a subclass of the list type.

Comment: Since some WCF configurations are not supported in ASP.NET Core, I recommend that you first create a **.net framework 4.8** or lower project to test.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, updating the System.ServiceModel.* NuGet packages solved it. Credit goes to @karatas.hakan, who answered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77298463/23650689).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).